# Run two python instances from one python file in sublime text

Tags: python, sublimetext

Suppose I have a python file which plot a simple `sin(a*x)` function. In sublime text, when I press `command+B`, the plot shows.

However, suppose I need to change the parameter `a` and compare the figure with the current one. A simple second press of `command+B` just close the current plot and generate a new one, which is not what I want cause I want to compare them side by side.

In PyCharm you have `allow parallel run` option, I wonder if sublime text can achieve this.

Comment: Why can't you have two graphs displayed in the same script?

Comment: @PotSkill You should ask why I even plot such a simple graph.

Comment: As PotSkill said, just plot two side-by-side graphs. *Why* you're plotting them doesn't matter.

Comment: @MattDMo This is a minumum example to illustarte my question, I am not asking a side by side plot. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: would be a good workaround opening second instance of sublimetext?

Comment: I assume from your tags that you haven't upgraded to ST4?

Comment: @OdatNurd I didn't notice it. It should be the newest version, build 4113.

Comment: @anoffercan'trefuse Which plotting library do you use? The Q seems around 2 plots side by side but heading says otherwise, are you okay with 2 plots sideways without 2 python instances?

Comment: @AdityaGuru No, I need to show the results of two runs at the same time.

Comment: can you create the two plots on a separate figure, then call `plt.show()` once? e.g. `fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(); ax1.plot(x, y1); fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(); ax2.plot(x, y2); plt.show()`? Otherwise, I think the answer is just "no"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sublime Text you have the option to open multiple terminals in multiple tabs, allowing you to keep 2 versions of the same python file running simultaneously. Here is a GIF demonstrating that:

[image]

Here are the steps:

1. Open the Command Pallette. It can be found in the Tools tab in the menu bar.
2. Enter "Terminus tab" into the search box and select the only option that will be displayed. A new tab will be opened, and there you can navigate to where your python file is located.
3. For the second terminal, repeat step 2.
4. Now you can run the same python file indepentantly in the 2 teminal tabs.

---

**To have the two terminal windows displayed below the python file**, go to the "View" tab, then "Layout", and select the "Rows: 2" option *(the window will be split into 2 windows)*. Open a terminus tab in the bottom window. Then, go to the Command Palette and enter "Terminus toggle" and select the only option. Now you have two terminal windows at the bottom of your file. Here is a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]

---

To have the terminals to be displayed side-by-side horizontally and not vertically *(like demonstrated above)*, select the "Grid: 4" instead of the "Columns: 2" option and open a terminus tab in the bottom two windows. Here is a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try saving the figure each time you run the script.  If you are using matplotlib, the savefig command will achieve that.  https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=savefig#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig

You can even append the time to the file name before saving so that you know which figure is which.

```py
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.savefig(time.localtime(time.time()) + '.pdf')
```